# shell script to process a folder path

Tags: shell

I am unable to process the following shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
P= '/mnt/temp/'
echo $P
Q= `echo $P` | sed -e "s/^.*\(.\)$/\1/"
echo 'Q is' $Q
echo ${P%?}
```

I expect the output as

```
/mnt/temp/
Q is /
/mnt/tmp
```

[edit]

As a next step I want to update remove the trailing / in P so am trying

```
if  ${Q} ="/"
then
   echo in
   P=${P%?}
fi
```

but on execution it says

```
/: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spaces are not allowed in variable assignation in [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), so :

```
#!/bin/sh
P='/mnt/temp/'
echo "$P"
Q=$(echo "$P" | sed -e "s/^.*\(.\)$/\1/")
echo "Q is $Q"
echo "${P%?}"
```

And use more quotes, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Thanks for solution and more for the useful links. Can you please help me with the follow up question.

Comment: `p=/foobar/; echo ${p%/}` : `?` is any character, no need to use it here, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe